# Why to run tensorflow on Linux?

Tags: linux, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am new to machine learning domain, and I have come across a lot of tutorials which say, "So now we are going to run Tensorflow, lets boot into Linux". Is there any specific advantage of running Tensorflow in Linux rather than Windows?

Comment: Just have a look at the number of "How do I get TF to run on windows?" question here ;-)

Comment: @dedObed I can run Tensorflow on Windows .. I just wanted to know if there was an advantage of running it on Linux. Dr. Snoopy has given a very well answer whereas you seem to have misunderstood my question and closed it already.

Comment: My comment is basically Dr. Snoopy's answer in one line ;-) And I didn't close the question, I'm neither convinced it deserves so nor do I have the power to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, there is a good reason. It is simply that TensorFlow has been developed, tested, and best supported on Linux (1st class citizen) while Windows and macOS are not that well tested, they are effectively 2nd class citizens of that platform.

And if you analyze, it makes sense, Linux is the backbone of most cloud computing and data center platforms, and I think most data scientists and researchers are running some kind of Linux platform to run their experiments. Even if people use Windows or macOS, they usually run experiments on Linux servers.

It has happened in the past that bugs in TensorFlow that only happened in Windows took longer to report and fix, just because it was not regularly tested on Windows. This might have changed now but I am not sure, still I estimate that the number of TensorFlow users on Windows and macOS are the far minority of TensorFlow users. You can even see this as Apple had create their own tensorflow fork ([tensorflow_macos](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos)) to properly support their platforms.

So, just choose Linux, it will be much easier to install and to use.